# Como fazer aplicação rodando em segundo plano o tempo todo

Tags: java, android, android-service, background-services

Tentei usar o `Service` como falaram mas não está funcionando ainda. Não sei se entendi direito, o método `onStartCommand()` vai ser executado o tempo todo? Pq eu depurei e a aplicação só entra nesse método uma vez, quando o `onCreate()` é chamado e eu preciso que o que está lá rode o tempo todo. Segue o código:

Servico.java

```
public class Servico extends Service {
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.e("oi", "onStartCommand");
        boolean ok = true;
        while(ok == true){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(30000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            gerarNotificacao();
       }
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

ExecutaServico.java

```
public class ExecutaServico extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if ("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED".equals(intent.getAction())) {
            Intent pushIntent = new Intent(context, Servico.class);
            context.startService(pushIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
<receiver android:name=".ExecutaServico">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:name=".Servico"/>

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

MainActivity.java

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    startService(new Intent(HomeActivity.this,Servico.class));
        final Button continuar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_continuar);
        continuar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
        //varias coisas
            }
       });
   }
}
```

Não tenho ideia do que fiz de errado... De 30 em 30 segundos a notificação deve aparecer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O que você precisa é de um `Service`, ele é executado mesmo quando sua aplicação é fechada, e você pode fazer com que ele execute mesmo se o usuário reiniciar o dispositivo.

Primeiro de tudo, vamos criar a sua classe de serviço

**TestService.java**

```
public class TestService extends Service
{
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onStartCommand");
        // START_STICKY serve para executar seu serviço até que você pare ele, é reiniciado automaticamente sempre que termina
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

No segundo passo, vamos criar um `BroadcastReceiver` para notificar o serviço para ser iniciado assim que o dispositivo iniciar.

**BootCompletedIntentReceiver.java**

```
public class BootCompletedIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if ("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED".equals(intent.getAction())) {
            Intent pushIntent = new Intent(context, TestService.class);
            context.startService(pushIntent);
        }
     }
}
```

Agora vamos declarar também na sua `MainActivity` para ela iniciar o serviço.

**MainActivity.java**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), TestService.class));
}
```

Por fim, temos que declarar no `Manifest` o `Service`, o `BroadcastReceiver` e a permissão para iniciar o serviço assim que o dispositivo terminar o boot.

**Manifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
 <application>
  <receiver android:name=".BootCompletedIntentReceiver">
   <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
   </intent-filter>
  </receiver>
  <service android:name=".TestService"/>
 </application>
```

Fazendo dessa forma você terá um serviço que é executado o tempo todo, mesmo que o dispositivo seja reiniciado.

---

**Alguns links que podem te ajudar também:**

[Autostart Service on Device Boot](http://www.jjoe64.com/2011/06/autostart-service-on-device-boot.html)

[How to automatically restart a service even if user force close it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21550204/how-to-automatically-restart-a-service-even-if-user-force-close-it)

[Android Services - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html)

[Serviços | Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)

Comment: Eu fiz oq vc falou, mas não está funcionando. Está dando esse erro: "ActivityThread: Performing stop of activity that is not resumed"

Comment: Deu certo, só mudei a chamada do Service para o onPause(), pq senão a aplicação n ia abrir... Muito obrigada! Desculpa por ter criado outra pergunta, é que precisava disso hj e não sabia se vc voltaria a tempo

Comment: Ok, fico feliz por ter dado certo, existe também a possibilidade de fazer o serviço reiniciar caso o usuário force o fechamento

Comment: como faço que o serviço reinicie no caso de um force closer? @VitorHenrique