# BroadCastReceiver dá erro com BOOT_COMPLETED

Tags: android

Preciso atualizar a cada 1h as informações e estou usando um `BroadCastReceiver`.
Se o usuário abrir o APP, ele funciona corretamente fazendo tudo a cada 1h.
Porém preciso que ele faça com o boot do celular e não só quando abrir o app.

Porém não sei por que, fala que o meu aplicativo parou após o celular ligar.
Não sei aonde está o erro, já que ele chega no final dos métodos.

Estou chamando o `AlarmService` assim:

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)){
        Intent i = new Intent(context,AlarmReceiver.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

No meu `AlarmService` está o seguinte código :
http://pastebin.com/F9yxhLsx

Pelo **LogCat**, vejo que ele está entrando até chegar no final do código.

```
CHEGOU FINAL ANTES abrir arquivo 
CHEGOU FINAL ANTES ESCREVER 
CHEGOU FINAL
```

Aonde poderia estar o erro?
Agradeço desde já pela atenção!

Comment: Você declarou a permissão `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>`no `Manifest.xml`? Edite e coloque o código da `exception` para facilitar a resolução do problema.

Comment: Sim,coloquei a permissão e o app está instalado no internal.não está dando nenhum exception,simplesmente para de responder.
Será que tem algo haver com o context.startActivity ?

Comment: Pode ser que sua `Intent` está vindo como `null`. Tenta comentar a linha `if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)){` e `}`, feito isso teste a aplicação. Você pode mudar também para `if("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED".equals(intent.getAction()))`.

Comment: Troquei o context.startActivity(i) para context.startService(i),agora ele executa,porém não chama os métodos do meu AlarmReceiver.Só entra em 2 métodos da minha MainActivity,sendo que não seria para entrar.

Comment: É realmente não tinha visto esta parte. Seu `AlarmReceiver` não deveria extender do `Service` e não do `BroadcastReceiver`? Pelo que entendi você quer usá-lo como um `Service`, certo?

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda,não sei muito a diferença dos 2,o que mudaria de um para o outro ?,irei tentar trocar pra service,se eu colocasse service,não daria erro no manifest do receiver por não extender BroadCastReceiver ?

Comment: Dá uma olhada aqui nesta pergunta que eu respondi hoje: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/137085/11421. Nela está bem explicado como funciona um `Service`e como você utiliza ele com o boot do dispositivo.

Comment: Olá,obrigado funcionou perfeitamente,como eu poderia adaptar para chamar o serviço a cada x horas ? ouvi falar que é com o AlarmManager e ja procurei um pouco,seria correto usar ele pra iniciar a cada x horas ?

Comment: OK amigo, vou colocar como resposta para as outras pessoas poderem ver. Quanto a sua outra dúvida, seria legal você criar uma nova pergunta com este assunto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pergunta respondida nos comentários, apenas movendo para aqui.

---

Troque o `context.startActivity(i)` por `context.startService(i)`.

Quanto a sua classe `AlarmReceiver`, creio que o que você precisa para atualizar as informações seja de um `Service`. Então você pode utilizar o seu `BootReceiver`para iniciar o `Service` quando o dispositivo realizar o boot.

---

**Este link vai te ajudar com o que você precisa:** [Como fazer aplicação rodando em segundo plano o tempo todo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/137085/11421)